# Preventing people from saving PDFs or adding a download date

Tags: javascript, security, pdf, save

We currently have a website where people have access to free forms for 3 years, which are downloadble as PDFs.

Is there anyway that we can prevent people from saving the pdf to their desktop, or if anybody can think of another solution?!

Alternatively can you add a download date to the PDF (so that this always appears after they re-open the download, if it is saved to their desktop)?

Comment: don't display pdfs...just display screenshots of the forms then.

Comment: Add a large nasty water mark "UNREGISTERED FORM - PAY TO REMOVE". TBH free forms for 3 years...? You'll be waiting 3 years on the *hope* that people start to pay... People will in reality just create new accounts with slight account name/email variations. And to answer your question... I seriously doubt it, a PDF is just a "file" from the point of view of the (Windows?) desktop.

Comment: Thank you for your replies. One of the benfits of attending our courses is that they have access to the free forms for 3 years (for use with their clients), so we want them to have high-res versions (I've tried displaying a JPEG, and overlaying a clear PNG so that they can't download the JPEG but the quality is poor if you reduce the file size down so that it automatically fits in the printable area). These forms are downloadable from a secure part of our website but there's nothing stopping them from saving them.